# Python graphene-graphql, are global constants for SQL queries a good idea?

Tags: python, mysql

For python 3.6.5 using graphene-graphql and mysql-connector

**Context:**
I wrote an API using [graphene](https://graphene-python.org/), a python [graphQL](https://graphql.org/learn/) implementation, this is actually my first time using the graphQL specification so I'm looking to improve my code implementation for the resolvers using a MySQL database.

As you may know, GraphQL isn't tied to any specific database or storage engine so it specifies a *resolve* method, where you "resolve" for a field in your *Type*. eg. **User** has a field **name**, so the resolve method would be *how* you get that name.

All my types are in a package: **mytypes** with modules for each type, and they all follow the same styling as the following code example.

**Code:**
Please note how the last two functions are different implementations I've tried, more on this on my concerns down below.

```
import graphene

from database.connection import request

from mytypes.user import User
from mytypes.format import Format

_STUDENT_ID   = 'SELECT student_id FROM Rubrics WHERE id = %s'
_EVALUATOR_ID = 'SELECT evaluator_id FROM Rubrics WHERE id = %s'
_PROJECT_NAME = 'SELECT project_name FROM Rubrics WHERE id = %s'

class Rubric(graphene.ObjectType):
    uid            = graphene.ID()
    evaluator      = graphene.Field(User)
    student        = graphene.Field(User)
    rubricFormat   = graphene.Field(Format)
    projectName    = graphene.String()
    evaluationDate = graphene.Date()
    isPublic       = graphene.Boolean()

    def resolve_evaluator(self, info):
        evaluator_id = request(_EVALUATOR_ID, self.uid)
        return User(uid=evaluator_id)

    def resolve_student(self, info):
        student_id = request(_STUDENT_ID, self.uid)
        return User(uid=student_id)

   def resolve_rubricFormat(self, info):
       request = 'SELECT format_id FROM Rubrics WHERE id = %s'
       format_id = make(request, self.uid)
       return Format(uid=format_id)

    def resolve_isPublic(self, info):
        return rubric.is_public(self.uid)
```

**Concerns:**

- **Readability**

My first concern is about readability, I'm trying to follow the [PEP 8 styling for Python code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which states that I shouldn't use or should avoid

> More than one space around an assignment (or other) operator to align it with another.

Which I do when defining my fields (uid, evaluator, student, etc), but this way it makes scanning it better in my opinion.

- **Resolve Implementation**

As for the two methods I mentioned, first for **resolve_rubricFormat** I like the way **make(request, self.uid)** was read, where "make" was the same request imported as **make** but I realized I was just over-complicating.

Then, for **resolve_isPublic** I was delegating the data fetching to a package **resolvers** that had modules for every type and had all the logic there, but switching between both the Type and its resolvers/gets at the other package was tiring not to mention the original resolve methods would lose their significance since I was calling another method that was doing what the original resolve was intended for.

- **Global Variables**

So I switched to global variables where I place the actual SQL query and use it as **request(_WHATEVER, id)** eg. request(_PROJECT_NAME, self.uid) would return the project name for the specified id, and since its on a module level its understood we are talking about the Rubric id.

But, I'm not sure if this is a good idea, what are your thoughts on this, any way to do it better?